# Windows Phone 8 Communication

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, windows-phone-8

I have various questions about windows phone 8 communications which I hope someone out there will be able to clarify.

1. What is the best method to communicate between a wp8 device and a server? WCF, OData, Json, Webclient, other? Does anyone know what is the recommend standard if any?
2. Based on 1, will using SSL or similar work? How do you encrypt data over the wire if SSL is not a an option.
3. Sample on how to use wcf (or other) using Async Await? The sample I'm working on, though not familiar with it all, I'm using wcf and I'm confused as to how I should go about it. Assume the following basic scenario:

   a) The user is provided with a logon page. The user then clicks Login.
   b) The proxy is first opened by calling the .Open (should I call openasync?).
   c) A wcf call is made to call the .LogonUser (should I call LogonUserAsync?).
   d) The proxy is then closed by calling .Close (should I call CloseAsync?).

Again I'm confused as if I don't use asynchronous call, it doesn't feel right, thought it might be ok. Can someone confirm this? Second, if I use async, should I call the .LogonUser from inside the OpenCompleted event and then call the .Close within the LogonUserCompleted? Seems messy and dirty coding? Again I could be completely off, but it just doesn't feel right?

Is there any good sample out there providing and explaining step by step on what should be the correct communication protocol that should be use and how to use it. Most of the wcf sample I'm finding never seem to call the .Open & .Close methods which I assume is a must and that's maybe why it is omitted but again, it's not obvious when you don't know what you're doing.

Should wcf (or any other) always call open & close for each call made i.e. logon, search, etc... rather than keeping this open for the entire session when the application is opened and re-using the same object?

Thanks and sorry for the many questions in one post.

Thanks.

T.

Answer (score 0):

#1 There is no rule of thumb to decide which is the best method amongst: WCF, OData, Json,
I think what should be used should be decided by the requirement. In Windows Phone you can use any of these,.

#2 If you are not using SSL, then you can think of private/public key encryption

#3 I am not sure about whether openasync() should be really used. In one of my project I have consumed WCF service without calling openasync(). You should use Aync methods.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. In regards to 3, strangely enough, it's only giving me the openasynch() method and not the .open() via wcf. I wanted to originally try to use the async method. Any ideas why?